flutter error: resource android:attr/lStar not found. while building release apk

ive tried everything(flutter upgrade, upgraded every dependency to latest still this error is not going) but it works fine in bedug build, only error happens in release version, is their any other way to solve this problem and please explain what can actually solve this

upgrade target version & compile sdk to 34 in build.gradle

@NaveenAvidi they are already 34

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
